# Reactjs-Popup: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forwardRef')

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-popup

Im trying to use the following documentation : https://react-popup.elazizi.com/component-api/
but always show the following error :Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forwardRef').
I cannot figure out how to make this popup listen to the const Custombutton ,how do I make it listen to value?

Fairly simple component here:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { ErrorMessage, useField } from "formik";
import { StyledTextInput, StyledLabel, StyledIcon, ErrorMsg } from "./Styles";

// Eye for password
import { FiEyeOff, FiEye } from "react-icons/fi";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

export const TextInput = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const [showpass, setShowpass] = useState(false);
  //const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  const CustomButton = React.forwardRef(({ open, ...props }, ref) => (
    <button className="button" ref={ref} {...props}>
      Trigger - {props.open ? "Opened" : "Closed"}
    </button>
  ))

  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <StyledLabel htmlFor={props.name}>{props.label}</StyledLabel>
      {props.type !== "password" && (
        <StyledTextInput
          invalid={meta.touched && meta.error}
          {...field}
          {...props}
        />
      )}
      {props.type === "password" && (
        <StyledTextInput
          invalid={meta.touched && meta.error}
          {...field}
          {...props}
          type={showpass ? "text" : "password"}
        />
      )}
      <StyledIcon>{icon}</StyledIcon>
      {props.type === "password" && (
        <StyledIcon onClick={() => setShowpass(!showpass)} right>
          {showpass && <FiEye />}
          {!showpass && <FiEyeOff />}
        </StyledIcon>
      )}
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <ErrorMsg>{meta.error}</ErrorMsg>
      ) : (
        <ErrorMsg style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>.</ErrorMsg>
      )}
      
      <Popup
        trigger={(open) => <CustomButton open={open} />}
        position="right center"
        closeOnDocumentClick
      >
        <span> Popup content </span>
      </Popup>
      ;
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to modify the React import :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

Comment: I know it sound too beginner ,but im......, so could you tell me the diference betwenn an import React and an import {React}

Comment: This is related to how JavaScript modules export things, and how you can import it. import React from 'react' means that React is the default export in the react module (where you can find "export default React"). import { useState } from 'react' means that react exports a thing named "useState", which is not the default export (export useState = ...). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: ...and nothing sounds "too beginner" :) !